# Взаимодействие с консольным приложением через Python

Tags: python

У меня есть очень простое консольное приложение (.exe), оно принимает ввод и отдает какой-то ответ. Мне нужно из python-скрипта отправлять в него ввод и получать ответ, на протяжении всей работы консольное приложение должно быть открыто. Я пытался через subprocess, однако у меня даже не получилось отправить текст в приложение, вот код и ошибка:

```
import subprocess
import os

current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
text = 'hello'.encode()
proc = subprocess.Popen(current_dir + '/ConsoleApp.exe', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(text)
result = proc.stdout.read()
print(result)
proc.wait()

����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.IO.IOException: ������ ���ਯ��.

   � System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   � System.Console.set_CursorSize(Int32 value)
   � CRT_implementation______.CRT_implementation______.__InitModule()
   � CRT_implementation______.CRT_implementation______.$Initialization()
   � ragebot.ragebot.$_Init_()
   � GamesBot.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Это ошибка в программе

Comment: если просто запускать программу, то проблем не возникает